# Log in from homepage using Container Managed Security

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, security

I am using container managed security with Tomcat.  I have a homepage at example.com that should be open to the public and a webapp at example.com/app that needs to be password protected.  I want to allow users to type their user names and passwords on the homepage and then be authenticated and directed to the webapp.

Currently I have to link the users from the homepage to example.com/app.  Tomcat then redirects them to my specified log in page, which makes a post to j_security_check, and then allows them access.  This solution is not satisfactory because the username and password text boxes are not on the homepage.

Please advise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the login form on the home page and declare the home page URI as `<form-login-page>`.